# Retrieving data from a sql database and displaying it in a table

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js

I am trying to retrieve a list of teams from a database and then display them in a table. I'm using underscore and JavaScript.

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="findPlayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="listTeams.html">Teams</a> | <a href="findPlayer.html">Find Player</a> 

<h1>Find Player [jQuery & UnderScore]</h1>

<hr>

Team Code:<input id="team" type="text" value="CLE">
Player Name:<input id="name" type="text" value="LeBron James">

<button id="find">Find</button>

<hr>

<table border=1>
    <tbody id="table">
        <tr><th>Team</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Pts</th></tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 

</body>
</html>
```

**ListTeams.js**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$.getJSON("getTeamData.php",function(data){
    console.log(data);
    _.each(data,function(element){
        $('#table').append('<tr><td>${element.NAME}</td></tr>');
    });
  });
});
```

This is supposed to add lines to my table with the names of 30 NBA teams, but what I actually get is rows with `${element.NAME}` in them.

How can I make my code display the team names correctly?

Comment: So what is the expected outcome of running your code? What is the actual outcome? What error messages do you get on your browser console?

Comment: Its supposed to list out 30 NBA teams but when i open the html file in the browser the table is created but every column has ${element.NAME}  in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to put the names in the tables. Note that you have to use backticks (`) for that, not single quotes ('), like this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("getTeamData.php",function(data){
        console.log(data);
        _.each(data,function(element){
            $('#table').append(`<tr><td>${element.NAME}</td></tr>`);
        });
    });
});
```

If you don't want to use template literals, you have to concatenate the string with the HTML, like this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("getTeamData.php",function(data){
        console.log(data);
        _.each(data,function(element){
            $('#table').append('<tr><td>' + element.NAME + '</td></tr>');
        });
    });
});
```